# Hyperledger fabric 2.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Getting the below error while trying to connect peer to channel in hyper-ledger fabric v 2.0 with couchbase 2,3

```
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded.
```

Can anyone suggest why this is happening?

Comment: Please share other information like network config, compose file.

Answer (score 0):

`peer channel create -o localhost:7050 -c mychannel --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com -f ./artifacts/channel/mychannel.tx --outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block --tls true --cafile $ORDERER_CA`

try this way to do this